# Maintain the natural sort of overall results, but sort a subfield array within each result in elasticsearch?

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, match, elastica

Our defined Type is something like this:

```
'title' => ... ,
'body' => ... ,
'links' => 'type'=>'object', 'properties'=> array
        'link' => ... ,
'locations' => 'type'=>'object', 'properties'=> array
        'label' => ... ,
        'pin' => ...
)
```

The records/documents represent businesses that reside in one or more categories, and so the links array will contain all of the potential links to a business, i.e.

```
[0] => '/Businesses/Hotels/My-Business/',
[1] => '/Businesses/Resorts/My-Business/',
[2] => '/Businesses/Fractional-Ownership/My-Business/'
```

So when we run a query on the terms `Business Resort` this listing is included in the result set.  At the moment though, we don't know which link would be most appropriate to display on the results page, so we just default to the first, in this case the one with `../Hotels/..` in the path.

**Is it possible to order the links according to their own score/relevancy within the search** so that the link order on the returned result would instead be:

```
[0] => '/Businesses/Resorts/My-Business/',
[1] => '/Businesses/Hotels/My-Business/',
[2] => '/Businesses/Fractional-Ownership/My-Business/'
```

The order of the links should not have any influence on the order of natural results from the overall query.

---

**EDIT :**   The second use case which I've added above is, we also store locations for each business, and would like to order the location list for each resulting business by their proximity to a set of coordinates.  We know how to order the entire result set by `_geo_distance` but need to know how to do it on a specific field, and like above, without affecting the overall result order.

Comment: I hope my answer helped, let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

[Script based sorting](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_script_based_sorting) will give you exactly what you want to sort on. But [track_scores](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_track_scores) seems it will do what you're looking for, sorting doesn't use scores by default.

And for ordering geo distance sorting by a specific field you could do so client side, providing the specific field value of the selected field? I'm not sure this answers your second question.

Comment: I appreciate the ideas Michael but neither of those options are related to sorting object lists from what I read, only sorting the primary result list using values within the object lists. I stated in my question `The order of the links should not have any influence on the order of natural results from the overall query.`  I'm only looking to ensure the object lists within a result record are ordered preferentially based on separate criteria.  I also asked for json examples, so if there's something I missed, please illustrate it. Thanks.

Comment: My apologies for not including examples, I didn't read the bounty description. I'll send some examples shortly, thank you for the feedback.